# Begin body scrolling, after Head Container reached min-height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a pretty simple page, if I scroll down, the height of my header reduces until its min-height, this works as I want. But the body scrolls simultaneously to decreasing the Height of my Head-Container. I'd like to let begin body scrolling after, Head-Container reached its min-height.

I added something like into the first if of my script:

```
if(st < 100)
{
  $("#Head").scrollTo(0);
}
```

but this doesn't work, as I override the right scrolling values.
Any suggestions? 
Thanks in advance, 
Johannes

```
<HTML>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var lastVal = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var st = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (st > lastVal){
            $("#Head").css({height: "+=" + (lastVal-st) + "px"});
        } else {
            $("#Head").css({height: "+=" + (st-lastVal) + "px"});
        }
        lastVal = st;
    });
});
</script>
<style TYPE="text/css">
#Head {
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    min-height: 100px;
    height: 230px;
    position: relative;
}

</style>
<BODY>
    <DIV id="main">
        <div id="Head">
            <h1>My Head</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
                        <P>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla sodales lorem et mauris feugiat eu interdum neque imperdiet. In ullamcorper laoreet blandit. Phasellus quis leo quam, ac adipiscing lectus. Aenean vulputate pharetra lorem sit amet scelerisque. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam ac ante mauris. Integer et diam ante. Aenean eu elit vel sem semper sagittis quis sit amet erat. Praesent fermentum, justo nec suscipit rhoncus, massa metus varius dolor, ac sollicitudin lectus risus nec est. Nunc venenatis justo at enim iaculis nec sagittis eros imperdiet. Fusce porta venenatis sodales. Curabitur molestie quam in arcu porttitor sollicitudin.
            </P><P>
                Proin egestas luctus sapien nec auctor. Aenean ut sapien leo, et euismod nulla. Suspendisse ac feugiat orci. Vestibulum vitae magna diam, non fringilla dui. Vivamus auctor mi ut eros egestas ut malesuada orci lobortis. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Proin ut ipsum feugiat ligula sagittis malesuada a vel orci. Sed sit amet nisl id risus sollicitudin venenatis. Donec lobortis facilisis mauris, sed eleifend nunc laoreet quis. Nulla neque orci, aliquam eget rhoncus ut, feugiat id erat. Duis orci sapien, dictum non pretium non, egestas in nisl.
            </P>
            <P>
                Aenean felis turpis, aliquet ac consectetur ac, pulvinar vitae dui. Aenean lacus lorem, rhoncus id dictum sit amet, luctus quis metus. Nullam posuere dignissim hendrerit. Nam tristique urna non neque laoreet nec porta tortor vestibulum. Ut varius facilisis vehicula. Vestibulum hendrerit pretium lorem, sit amet aliquet nisi porta eget. Sed sapien nunc, viverra et vehicula fringilla, cursus vitae mauris. Curabitur commodo mi eu lorem pulvinar auctor. Praesent et sapien et massa ultricies dignissim id at velit. Proin fringilla orci rutrum lacus hendrerit eu cursus quam auctor. 
            </p> 
                <P>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla sodales lorem et mauris feugiat eu interdum neque imperdiet. In ullamcorper laoreet blandit. Phasellus quis leo quam, ac adipiscing lectus. Aenean vulputate pharetra lorem sit amet scelerisque. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam ac ante mauris. Integer et diam ante. Aenean eu elit vel sem semper sagittis quis sit amet erat. Praesent fermentum, justo nec suscipit rhoncus, massa metus varius dolor, ac sollicitudin lectus risus nec est. Nunc venenatis justo at enim iaculis nec sagittis eros imperdiet. Fusce porta venenatis sodales. Curabitur molestie quam in arcu porttitor sollicitudin.
            </P><P>
                Proin egestas luctus sapien nec auctor. Aenean ut sapien leo, et euismod nulla. Suspendisse ac feugiat orci. Vestibulum vitae magna diam, non fringilla dui. Vivamus auctor mi ut eros egestas ut malesuada orci lobortis. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Proin ut ipsum feugiat ligula sagittis malesuada a vel orci. Sed sit amet nisl id risus sollicitudin venenatis. Donec lobortis facilisis mauris, sed eleifend nunc laoreet quis. Nulla neque orci, aliquam eget rhoncus ut, feugiat id erat. Duis orci sapien, dictum non pretium non, egestas in nisl.
            </P>
                <P>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla sodales lorem et mauris feugiat eu interdum neque imperdiet. In ullamcorper laoreet blandit. Phasellus quis leo quam, ac adipiscing lectus. Aenean vulputate pharetra lorem sit amet scelerisque. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam ac ante mauris. Integer et diam ante. Aenean eu elit vel sem semper sagittis quis sit amet erat. Praesent fermentum, justo nec suscipit rhoncus, massa metus varius dolor, ac sollicitudin lectus risus nec est. Nunc venenatis justo at enim iaculis nec sagittis eros imperdiet. Fusce porta venenatis sodales. Curabitur molestie quam in arcu porttitor sollicitudin.
            </P><P>
                Proin egestas luctus sapien nec auctor. Aenean ut sapien leo, et euismod nulla. Suspendisse ac feugiat orci. Vestibulum vitae magna diam, non fringilla dui. Vivamus auctor mi ut eros egestas ut malesuada orci lobortis. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Proin ut ipsum feugiat ligula sagittis malesuada a vel orci. Sed sit amet nisl id risus sollicitudin venenatis. Donec lobortis facilisis mauris, sed eleifend nunc laoreet quis. Nulla neque orci, aliquam eget rhoncus ut, feugiat id erat. Duis orci sapien, dictum non pretium non, egestas in nisl.
            </P>
                <P>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla sodales lorem et mauris feugiat eu interdum neque imperdiet. In ullamcorper laoreet blandit. Phasellus quis leo quam, ac adipiscing lectus. Aenean vulputate pharetra lorem sit amet scelerisque. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam ac ante mauris. Integer et diam ante. Aenean eu elit vel sem semper sagittis quis sit amet erat. Praesent fermentum, justo nec suscipit rhoncus, massa metus varius dolor, ac sollicitudin lectus risus nec est. Nunc venenatis justo at enim iaculis nec sagittis eros imperdiet. Fusce porta venenatis sodales. Curabitur molestie quam in arcu porttitor sollicitudin.
            </P><P>
                Proin egestas luctus sapien nec auctor. Aenean ut sapien leo, et euismod nulla. Suspendisse ac feugiat orci. Vestibulum vitae magna diam, non fringilla dui. Vivamus auctor mi ut eros egestas ut malesuada orci lobortis. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Proin ut ipsum feugiat ligula sagittis malesuada a vel orci. Sed sit amet nisl id risus sollicitudin venenatis. Donec lobortis facilisis mauris, sed eleifend nunc laoreet quis. Nulla neque orci, aliquam eget rhoncus ut, feugiat id erat. Duis orci sapien, dictum non pretium non, egestas in nisl.
            </P>
                <P>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla sodales lorem et mauris feugiat eu interdum neque imperdiet. In ullamcorper laoreet blandit. Phasellus quis leo quam, ac adipiscing lectus. Aenean vulputate pharetra lorem sit amet scelerisque. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam ac ante mauris. Integer et diam ante. Aenean eu elit vel sem semper sagittis quis sit amet erat. Praesent fermentum, justo nec suscipit rhoncus, massa metus varius dolor, ac sollicitudin lectus risus nec est. Nunc venenatis justo at enim iaculis nec sagittis eros imperdiet. Fusce porta venenatis sodales. Curabitur molestie quam in arcu porttitor sollicitudin.
            </P><P>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla sodales lorem et mauris feugiat eu interdum neque imperdiet. In ullamcorper laoreet blandit. Phasellus quis leo quam, ac adipiscing lectus. Aenean vulputate pharetra lorem sit amet scelerisque. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam ac ante mauris. Integer et diam ante. Aenean eu elit vel sem semper sagittis quis sit amet erat. Praesent fermentum, justo nec suscipit rhoncus, massa metus varius dolor, ac sollicitudin lectus risus nec est. Nunc venenatis justo at enim iaculis nec sagittis eros imperdiet. Fusce porta venenatis sodales. Curabitur molestie quam in arcu porttitor sollicitudin.
            </P><P>
                Proin egestas luctus sapien nec auctor. Aenean ut sapien leo, et euismod nulla. Suspendisse ac feugiat orci. Vestibulum vitae magna diam, non fringilla dui. Vivamus auctor mi ut eros egestas ut malesuada orci lobortis. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Proin ut ipsum feugiat ligula sagittis malesuada a vel orci. Sed sit amet nisl id risus sollicitudin venenatis. Donec lobortis facilisis mauris, sed eleifend nunc laoreet quis. Nulla neque orci, aliquam eget rhoncus ut, feugiat id erat. Duis orci sapien, dictum non pretium non, egestas in nisl.
            </P>
                <P>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla sodales lorem et mauris feugiat eu interdum neque imperdiet. In ullamcorper laoreet blandit. Phasellus quis leo quam, ac adipiscing lectus. Aenean vulputate pharetra lorem sit amet scelerisque. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam ac ante mauris. Integer et diam ante. Aenean eu elit vel sem semper sagittis quis sit amet erat. Praesent fermentum, justo nec suscipit rhoncus, massa metus varius dolor, ac sollicitudin lectus risus nec est. Nunc venenatis justo at enim iaculis nec sagittis eros imperdiet. Fusce porta venenatis sodales. Curabitur molestie quam in arcu porttitor sollicitudin.
            </P><P>
                Aenean felis turpis, aliquet ac consectetur ac, pulvinar vitae dui. Aenean lacus lorem, rhoncus id dictum sit amet, luctus quis metus. Nullam posuere dignissim hendrerit. Nam tristique urna non neque laoreet nec porta tortor vestibulum. Ut varius facilisis vehicula. Vestibulum hendrerit pretium lorem, sit amet aliquet nisi porta eget. Sed sapien nunc, viverra et vehicula fringilla, cursus vitae mauris. Curabitur commodo mi eu lorem pulvinar auctor. Praesent et sapien et massa ultricies dignissim id at velit. Proin fringilla orci rutrum lacus hendrerit eu cursus quam auctor. 
            </p>        
        </div>
    </DIV>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Do you mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/vu4n386g/

Comment: **[This link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4770179/2065039)** might be helpful.. :)

Comment: Tanks for your comments, as long as I understand them, these do not fit my need, I tried to make my question more precise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple trick will do that.
If the `height` of header is greater than `min-height` and scroll to the top.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var st = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (st > lastVal){
        $("#Head").css({height: "+=" + (lastVal-st) + "px"});
        if($("#Head").css('height') > $("#Head").css('min-height')){
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        }
    } else {
        $("#Head").css({height: "+=" + (st-lastVal) + "px"});
    }
    lastVal = st;
});
```